# Bootstrap list of links with external icon after each list item

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, list

I am attempting to build a list of links. After each link, I want to place the font awesome icon for a "new tab" connection to the same site.  So the user can click on the link and open the page in the same window.  Or they can click the icon and open the page in a new window.

Here is what I have tried (python django template language):

```
<div class="list-group">
{% for link in object.links.all %}
  <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="list-group-item">{{ link.title }}</a><a href="{{ link.url }}" target=_blank><i class="fa fa-external-link"></a>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

This code produces a list of link names with the icon on a new list row under the name.  I am assuming the css is thinking that the second anchor is a new list item.

How do I get it placed right behind the original link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use css to keep text and icon on the same line:

```
.list-group a { display: inline-block; }
```

This will try to jam as many 'a elements' onto one line, so you need to add a line break at the end of each line.

```
<div class="list-group">
{% for link in object.links.all %}
  <a href="{{ link.url }}" class="list-group-item">{{ link.title }}</a><a href="{{ link.url }}" target=_blank><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a> <br/>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

You also forgot to close your i closing tag ;)

example: https://jsfiddle.net/krnnuxb1/

Comment: I did line them up but bootstrap placed the link inside of a div with a border and put the icon outside the border next to it.  Thanks!